# the type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect type interface failed in the call to join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I had written below line of code, in which user.Id is taken from IdentityUser "in built Id which is provided by IdentityUser", the data type of it is TKey and it is showing me error when i tried to cast it to Guid. I am trying to take join between two tables by comparing using Id in both the tables.

```
var data = from  collaborator in this.Context.Collaborators  join  user 
in this.Context.UserRegistrationsTable
on collaborator.UserId  equals user.Id 
where collaborator.ReceiverEmail == receiverEmail
select new
{
collaborator.ReceiverEmail,
collaborator.NoteId
};
```

Comment: `TKey` isn't a data type. It's a generic type parameter that should be specified when defining IdentityUser. What are the data types of `collaborator.UserId` and `user.Id`?

Comment: collaborator.UserId data type string and  user.Id data type is  TKey . In IdentityUser Id is an inbuilt feature , i tried to override ID with guid or string data type but it gives "error :  can't override Id in IdentityUser"

Comment: Again, `TKey` is not a data type. But apparently the ASP.Net-core identity is configured as `IdentityUser<Guid>`, so why is `collaborator.UserId` just a string?